# 2 azure functions and execute them in order

Tags: c#, azure, dependencies, azure-functions

I have 2 azure functions (2 different resources), which should be executed :

- function 1
- function 2
- function 1
- function 2
  etc
  and only in such order

So, when function 1 is being executed, function 2 waits. And vice versa.
If function 1, for example, executed failed, we execute function 2 (not retry function 1). And vice versa.

How to organize it?

Comment: Could you add more details please ? it is http triggered, queue triggered ? what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: As mentioned by Peter also, you can try using [Durable functions - > Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-external-events?tabs=csharp)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. If you want orchestration you can try using [Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-orchestrations?tabs=csharp). You then have an orchestration function that can call the other two in the right order.

Are you sure you need to different functions? The other option is to have just one function and program the logic in such a way that two methods inside the function do what you want them to do in the right order.

Comment: yes, there are 2 different projects with different dependencies etc

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by queueing:

Function 1 puts data in 1 queue, which Function 2 subscribe to.
So when Function 1 fails it puts a data in queue, where in Function 2 queue trigger takes it and executes.